# Buscar dados via SQL usando Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Preciso fazer um select para me retornar todos os usuários que possuam as iniciais de um nome.

Exemplo:

Eu digito no meu campo input de busca: "paulo" me retorna todos os usuários que tenham essa palavra.

Fiz uma pesquisa e usei isso:

```
$usuarios = User::where('nome', 'LIKE', $search. '%')                
                ->paginate(); 
            return view('auth.adm.lista', compact( 'usuarios', 'title'));
```

Esse código me retorna 15 usuários.

Porém se vou no PHPMYADMIN e digito esse sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE nome LIKE 'paulo%'
```

A linha acima retorna 44 usuários.

Onde posso estar errando que acaba limitando a 15 a busca no laravel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No [paginate](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination) é o retorna em página (*ou seja, pagina 1, pagina 2 e assim conforme página tiverem com esse resultado*):

```
$usuarios = User::where('nome', 'LIKE', $search. '%')                
                ->paginate();  // isso retorna somente 15 registros
```

que por padrão o método `paginate` retorna 15 registros por vez, mas, isso pode ser configurado para retornar outra quantidade, exemplo: ***10*** registros o código é o seguinte: `->paginate(10)` consequentemente a paginação é de 10 em 10 registros.

---

Se quiser retornar todos os registro utilize o método [get()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results):

```
$usuarios = User::where('nome', 'LIKE', $search. '%')                
                ->get(); // retorna todas da pesquisa sem paginação.
```

<sup>***Leia a documentação:*** [Database: Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination)</sup>